# In a MongoDB will an index help when a field is just being tested on its length?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I am creating a routine to check for interrupted processing and to carry on, during the startup I'm performing the following search:

```
.find({"DocumentsPath": {$exists: true, $not: {$size: 0}}})
```

I want it to be as fast as possible, however the documentation suggests that the index is for scanning within the data. I never need to search within the `"DocumentsPath"` just use it if its there. Creating an index seems like an overhead I don't want. However having the index might speed up the size test.

My question is whether this field should be indexed within the DB?

Comment: The BSON spec does say that field length is stored as such querable via index however, as to whether an $size does: have yuo actually tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought of commenting but this does deserve an answer. Should this be indexed? Well probably, but for other purposes. Does this make a difference here? No it does not.

The big point to make is your query terms are redundant ( or could be better ) in this case. Let's look at the example:

```js
{ "DocumentsPath": { "$exists": true } }
```

That will tell you if there is actually an element in a document that matches the property specified. No it does not an cannot use an index. You can use a ["sparse"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) index though and not even need to call that.

```js
{ "DocumentsPath": { "$not": { "$size" : 0 } } }
```

This is cute one. Yes it tests the length of an array, but what you are really asking here is "I don't want the array to be empty".

So for the better solution.

1. Use a "sparse" index:

   ```js
   db.collection.ensureIndex({ "DocumentsPath": 1 }, { "sparse": true })
   ```
2. Query for the zeroth element of an index

   ```js
   { "DocumentsPath.0": { "$exists": true } }
   ```

Still no index for "matching" really, but at least the "sparse" index sorted out some of that my excluding documents and the ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) form here is actually more efficient than evaluating via [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/).